# sort a JS string array by a specific letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I have to sort an array of strings like this:

```
var arr = ["akaw","waka","kawa","akwa"];
```

The type of sort must be by a specific letter, W in this case so my function must return this array:

```
arr = ["waka","kawa","akwa","akaw"];
```

It's a dynamic array and I don't know the number of words in array and if each words have no letter W, one W or some W.

Do you know a type of sort function to do that?

Thx!

Comment: just sort by W in this example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compare the index of the letter.

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.indexOf("w") - b.indexOf("w");
})
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/KrqmM

```
waka
kawa
akwa
akaw
```