# Sorting a Select List (A-Z) in React

Tags: javascript

Having a hard time figuring this out, how do I sort this select list alphabetically in React?

```
<select
  ref="userInput"
  required
  className="form-control"
  value={this.state.make}
  onChange={this.onChangeMake}
>
  {this.state.makes.map(function(make) {
    return (
      <option key={make} value={make}>
        {make}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript)

Comment: You could try `this.state.makes.slice().sort().map(...)`

Comment: @Tholle the option shows alphabetically now with this code
`this.state.makes.slice().sort().map(function(make)`

thanks :)

`value={this.state.make}`

any idea how to make the value show alphabetically too?

Comment: @avidrunner I'm not sure what you mean by "make the value show alphabetically too". Do you want to save the option string sorted alphabetically in your component state?

Comment: Verbiage: by "in React" you mean "in JavaScript". React is a UI library; you don't sort in it.

Comment: @Tholle the options show up alphabetically now when I click the dropdown but it still shows the first entry I have added as the default “value” before clicking the dropdown, rather than showing the first A-Z or even a default value “Add Make” would work fine. Sorry am new to React hope that makes sense

Comment: If you want a value not in the list, like an "empty" value, then you need to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use sort function js

```
<select
ref="userInput"
required
className="form-control"
value={this.state.make}
onChange={this.onChangeMake}
>
{this.state.makes.sort().map(function(make) {
 return (
  <option key={make} value={make}>
    {make}
  </option>
);
})}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you :)  Is there any way to get it working with words that start with Š characters for example?  Currently, it shows at the end of the list rather than in between R and T.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17118836/8731674 maybe this can help

Comment: Unfortunately didn't seem to work, still looking for solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method with `sort()`.

```js
this.state.makes.sort((a,b) => a > b ? 1 : -1).map(function(make) {
 return (
  <option key={make} value={make}>
    {make}
  </option>
  );
});
```

Source: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-sort-array-of-objects